# Help identifying connector

Tags: integrated-circuit, connector, socket

I'm making a new prototype PCB that unfortunately has some elements that are prone to failure, so I'm trying to design them to be easily swappable.

I'm taking inspiration from this design of using an additional PCB with a socket:
[image: Modular PCB]
[image: PCB Socket]
[image: PCB Assembly]

But I'm having trouble finding this or similar.

I could just use any old stacking connector, or 2.54mm headers, but I like the mechanical stability this brings.

If anyone knows a similar part (to the white socket) or even specific keywords I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

BTW, Pictures came from [here](http://www.yeitechnology.com/productdisplay/3-space-embedded-evaluation-kit-0)

Comment: What is failing?  The first thing I'd look at is why the component if failing so often and what could be done to stress it less.  You can use quite a few electronic parts before you get to the cost of the fancy connector and the process of having to replace the board.

Comment: The connector in your picture is a test/evaluation socket for a module that's meant to be soldered directly to a host PCB in actual use. As such, it is highly customized for each module design, and it is never produced in high quantity, so the price will be very high. All of the major connector manufacturers make good low-profile board-to-board connector sets, so you just need to start browsing until you see something you like.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know they were uncommon. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Connectors are always a dog's breakfast.. In Digikey's search engine, try "Rectangular Connectors, Spring Loaded".

Below is a similar type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Samtec have "one piece" connectors in either power or micro pitch, http://www.samtec.com/connectors/micro-pitch-board-to-board/compression-one-piece.aspx. They have the advantage that you only need to mount a connector on one board, the other one has contacts formed by the PCB manufacturing process. It doesn't look like they do a two row version, so you have to use two of these to replicate the mechanics of your white connector.